# How to use scroll view and gesture detect on the one widget page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I've faced a problem with scrolling on my flutter application. I've created a widget with `SingleChildScrollView` as a top of the widget in the tree. Then I've added `GestureDetector` to manipulate over my map. Rest of the screen will contain a simple column or text (but a lot of them so I need to scroll). This is a simple layout I want to achive [Desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SVS6.png).

Pseudocode:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children:[
      ScreenTitle("Title"),
      GestureDetector(child: Map()),
      Text("Lorem ipsum"),
      Text("Lorem ipsum"),
      ...
    ]
  )
);
```

The problem is with the scroll priority. When I tap horizontly on Map widget everything works, but if I tap vertically, SingleChildScrollView catch this gesture and scroll entire page. I want to catch all gesture for my Map and only if user tap somewhere else it should be delegated to SingleChildScrollView.

Of course without SingleChildScrollView, my GestureDetect works fine but... the text is behinde the visible area.

I want to catch every Gesture on my map widget and delegate to SingleChildScrollView only events not from Gesture.
I tried to remove SCSV and replaced it by ListView (the same problem).

Comment: I think I found in releated questions an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68621728/use-onpan-gesturedetector-inside-a-singlechildscrollview?rq=2 but from my point of view it is an ugly hack :( Maybe right now is better solutions ?

Comment: If you are using google maps ,check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280541/google-map-in-flutter-not-responding-to-touch-events

Comment: Unfortunetlly I use my own map, to be honest it is a picture that I can zoom and span :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired layout, you can wrap your `Column` widget inside a `ListView` widget. The `ListView` will allow you to scroll through the column's children, and the `GestureDetector` will allow you to manipulate the map.

Here's an example of how you can achieve the desired layout:

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
  child: ListView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // disable scrolling of the ListView
    shrinkWrap: true, // allow the ListView to take up only the necessary space
    children: [
      ScreenTitle("Title"),
      GestureDetector(
        child: Map(),
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque, // make sure the gesture detector is opaque to avoid conflicts with scrolling
      ),
      Text("Lorem ipsum"),
      Text("Lorem ipsum"),
      // more text widgets
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your map to be independent from your `SingleChildScrollView` then extract it out of it, like this:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      child: Map(),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[],
        )
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

It’s important to wrap the `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded` because other wise you will get render errors.