# Flutter GestureDetector onScaleStart is not triggered while being a child of ListView

Tags: flutter

I have a ListView and inside it a GestureDetector + other items afterward.
I notice that onScaleStart is never triggered when the page has enough content to require a scrollbar, but onTap is (listview scroll is "consuming" swipe up down events).

If I put my item outside the ListView it works as expected and scales

Any way to solve this ? I need to have the gesturedetector inside a ListView because there are other items below and I need the scrollbar

Please note, the onScaleStart works fine if there are few content and the scrollbar is not activated. If I have enough widgets to trigger ListView to use the scrollbar then the onScaleStart is never triggered.

Some minimalistic code to show it, extracted from the real code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onScaleStart: () {
                    // never called when there are enough widgets to enable the scroll of listview
                  },
                  onScaleUpdate: () {
                    // never called when there are enough widgets to enable the scroll of listview
                  },
                  child: Transform(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    transform: Matrix4.identity()
                      ..scale(_scale, _scale),
                    child: SomeChild(),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        AppIcons.three_dots_vertical,
                        size: 20,
                        color: Colors.white70,
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Dimen.spacingSmall),
                child: OtherWidget())
          ],
        ),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: SomeOtherWidget())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the onScaleStart/Update get called when you pinch to scale horizontally?

Comment: I uploaded a reproducible example at https://github.com/kristijorgji/flutter_tui/ . You can run that flutter project on a device and "swipe down" on the `ResizableImagesSlider`. You will notice that it works fine if the list has few items (adjust faker to have 1-2 items), and it will not zoom-in if the listview is using the scroll (height of page requires a scroll)

Comment: The project you shared does not seem to be compiling, may be because of outdated dependencies.
It would be easier if you can provide it in dartpad.dev

Comment: I created this project a couple of days ago using last flutter. I would say maybe you are not using up to date flutter. You can check the source code there in the project, the file user view contains the resizableimageslider inside the list view

Comment: I am talking about dependencies, not the Flutter version. It would be best to run flutter pub outdated to see the obsolete packages. One is even discontinued.

Comment: I am not sure about that, i can install and run it fine on a fresh new pc with same project

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Flutter has a problem distinguishing between scrolling and scaling gestures. I would recommend using `Listener`. Based on the number of tap events recorded, you can adjust the scrollability of your `ListView`. Here is a quick guide how you could hack the system.

Introduce two state variables: `_touchPoints` to count the number of active touch points on the screen and `_isScrollable` to determine if the `ListView` should be scrollable.

```
int _touchPoints = 0;
bool _isScrollable = true;
```

Detect Touch Points with `Listener`: Wrap your `ListView` with a `Listener` to detect touch points.

```
Listener(
  onPointerDown: (_) => _touchPoints++,
  onPointerUp: (_) => _touchPoints--,
  //...
)
```

Toggle Scrollability: Within the touch point detection callbacks, toggle `_isScrollable` based on the number of active touch points.

```
setState(() {
  if (_touchPoints > 1) _isScrollable = false;
  else _isScrollable = true;
});
```

Set `ListView` Physics: Conditionally set the physics of the `ListView` based on `_isScrollable`.

```
ListView(
  physics: _isScrollable ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  //...
)
```

Comment: hi thanks forr the answer Mike! (I was thinking if somethiing like this was possible). But will this say that I tap on listview even when i tap  on the resizableScroller... Havve to try it out if it works. In principle it works if I use neverscrollablephysics all is fine with slider but scroll does not scroll. My code is here https://github.com/kristijorgji/flutter_tui/ `user_view`

Comment: I tested it, it should work.

Comment: do you mind making a branch  with your code ? I can test and award  the bounty if it works fine. What did you  wrap the listview or the imageslider , in answer here you mention you wrap the  listview. This is what I don't understand, if it wraps the listview then resizableslider is ppart of listview and am afraid will receive the taps as well and we use "alwaysscrollable"

Comment: I actually can't run your code:
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-2.3.3/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1: Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'.
import 'asset_manifest.dart'; 

What flutter version you are using?

Comment: flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.12 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 4d9e56e694 (6 months ago) • 2023-04-17 21:47:46 -0400
Engine • revision 1a65d409c7
Tools • Dart 2.19.6 • DevTools 2.20.1

Comment: I tested very well carefully before posting in github. You should be able to run fine with the flutter version above like I can do: https://ibb.co/ctzJxfG

Comment: I opened a PR, feel free to check it out. Horizontal and vertical scaling works too.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I checked out to your branch and run it on my s22 device and the issue is still there. It is very buggy sometimes both things scroll down https://www.youtube.com/shorts/451vL2CeMPw

Comment: Also don't hardcode this to 10, `return List.generate(10, (index) {` but keep the faker one. The issue existed in the original version without your changes only when the page had enough content for the ListView to use a scroll. If the list had only 1 item, swiping down on the resizableimageslider worked great! as I need it to work even when the list has more items

Comment: I am not here to solve your whole app lol. The original issue was to solve onScaleStart to work with Listview. My solution works with a hardcoded list, but fixing the app to work with random list is out of the scope of this issue. You need to open other Stackoverflow questions for that. I consider the work done here.

Comment: That is true but also that is not my whole app. It is only the part that I described in this question that is still broken. The solution need to be provided for the given problem and if you change the problem statement for instance to have only 1 item in the list then the problem is gone by itself without any solution actually. Try that out you will see will work just fine. While appreciating the effort this is not a solution as does not fix the statement.

Comment: The problem is that with every rebuild you will get a new list, and this is ehy scrolling is not working for you. I worked with a given list for a reason. You need to figure out where you create your random list otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Ok makes sense. I will replace the random list with a fixed large list and try again. In my real use case the list is fixed (has a fixed number of items). The code I shared is only illustrative. I had random list only to show the problem that for small list existing code worked fine, for large list did not work

Comment: I tried with fixed value of 20 and the result is again like the video... there is no change in result